# Dynamic v-model witout nesting

Tags: vue.js

I know how to bind `v-model` dynamically to a nested data. For example:

```
   <input v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" v-model="item.name">
    
    data() {
       return {
                items: [
                        { type: "cat", name:"Smurf" },
                        { type: "dog", name: "Ruff" }
                       ]
              }
           }
```

But is there a way to omit this nesting and binding directly to unique data properties? For example, this code doesn't work, but maybe there is a solution?

```
<input v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" v-model="[item]">

data() { 
         return {
           items: ['dog', 'cat']
           cat: "Smurf", 
           dog: "Ruff" 
         }
```

Comment: you have a list of cats not just one cat. I don't understand the question

Comment: i don't see any problem your code or I don't understand your question properly. If you were saying your code can't compile, maybe is your second object forgot to put quote on the dog type like this, { type: "dog", name: "Ruff" }

Comment: This code is just an example. The question is about how to bind property to v-model dynamically without  parent object/array. e.g. If I had primitive data properties cat: "", dog: "" and I wanted to bind it to v-model without v-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can display all you component's data in the template with `{{ $data }}`. Hence you can access your property dynamically e.g.

```
<input v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" v-model="$data[item]">

data() { 
         return {
           items: ['dog', 'cat']
           cat: "Smurf", 
           dog: "Ruff" 
         }
       }
```